# Direct url and refresh page get 404 error - htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I know I should to redirect request to `index.html` with `htaccess`.

like this:

```
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

This is my `htaccess` (forced to use `www`):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shadyab.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.shadyab.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpe?g|gif)$ [NC]
```

But I don't know how to use or combine to above roles with `RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]`.

Is there any method to handle `index.html` file without `RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]`?

I get **404 error** when I refresh page, for example this url:

http://www.shadyab.com/offers/Restaurant-shams-o-emare-Off

Comment: Why have you tagged `javascript` and `reactjs`? The only tags for this should be URL/Domain related and `.htaccess`

Comment: Is there any way inside `react js` to handle requests?

Comment: Have you done any research to find out? So far you have only given the problem but haven't explain what you have tried or the research you have done...

Comment: Does the url `http://www.shadyab.com/offers/Restaurant-shams-o-emare-Off` actually exist in your file system or is it a rewritten url?

Comment: yes. it exists. all of my urls when I refresh page I got 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set order of indexing pages with something like this :

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
      DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

but I think you are looking for routing a link to index page . which can be done by matching `URL` and setting a `Rewrite`

```
RewriteRule ^offers/([^/]*)$ /index.php?name=$1 [L]
```